# When using the `Format$()` function, is there a simple format expression to display all digits to the right of the decimal?

Tags: vba

When using the `Format$()` function in VBA, is there a simple format expression to display all digits to the right of the decimal?

In order to display all decimal digits, the format expression must contain the decimal and as many `#` characters for potential displayable decimal digits in the number. This would be 7, 15, and 29 for `Single`, `Double`, and `Decimal`, respectively.

Also, if there aren't enough `#`, it will round off the last decimal digit, which may be undesirable.

But `Format$(n,"#.###############")` for a `Double` is a bit long, and even longer for `Decimal` with 29 displayable decimal digits, and thus 29 `#` would be needed.

Is there any shorthand for "show all decimal digits"?

The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-numeric-formats) section for `Decimal Placeholder` doesn't mention anything like this.

For instance:

```
Public Sub TestFormat()
    Dim n As Double
    n = 0.123456789012345
    Debug.Print Format$(n, "#.###############")
End Sub

Results:
0.123456789012345

'Is there any format character for "show all decimal digits", such as
'the asterisk below? (shown as an example - it is not real)
'Debug.Print Format$(n, "#.*")
```

**EDIT**: For clarity, all references to Pi() or EXP() have been removed. They were used as examples of long numbers, but instead muddled the intended question in the OP.

Comment: `cstr(exp(1))`?

Comment: @GSerg An easy way to get a number with lots of decimal places. Like Pi, but VBA doesn't have 
 a built-in function for that.

Comment: You can't even `exp(1)` or `Pi()` does only show a tiny part of all digits to the right. So, IMHO, question is what are you really after and what is it good for.

Comment: @Storax it was used simply as an example. The question is about `Format$()`, not `Exp()`.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to remove exp(1).

Comment: As suggested by GSerg and shown in my answer `Cstr` should do the job

Comment: What application are you running this code within? Excel?

Comment: @TylerH - yes, Excel. But I chose not to indicate that since `Format()` comes from the `VBA` library. I know there are ways to do it with `WorksheetFunction`, but my question is meant to focus on `VBA` just for the knowledge of it. Also, there is a chance this may show up in my `Word` macros with code I use there to pull SQL data into tables via `Adodb`. And of course I could to the rounding in SQL, but I digress...

Comment: @spinjector The reason I ask is, when using the [tag:vba] tag, you are typically supposed to tag the question with the application(s) you are applying the VBA code to, since the VBA functionality available is often application-dependent. But if your code is intended to be application-agnostic, that's OK. Just wanted to check :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following examples. IMHO `Format$` is not needed at all

```
Sub testDigits()
    
    Dim d As Variant
    
    ' d will be decimal and contain all "relevant" digits
    d = CDec(Exp(1)): Debug.Print d
    Range("A1").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
    
    ' d will be double but as Exp(1) is double and equal to 2,71828182845905
    ' no digits/information  will be lost
    d = Exp(1): Debug.Print d
    Range("B1").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
    
    ' d will be decimal and will contain all "relevant" digits
    d = CDec(1) / CDec(11): Debug.Print d
    Range("A2").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
    
    ' d will be double and and "cut off" after 16 digits
    d = 1 / 11: Debug.Print d
    Range("B2").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
        
    ' d will be decimal and contain all "relevant" digits
    d = CDec(1) / CDec(10): Debug.Print d
    Range("A3").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
    
    ' d will be decimal but as Pi() is doubly anyway and is equal to 3,14159265358979
    ' no digits/information  will be lost
    d = CDec(WorksheetFunction.Pi): Debug.Print d
    Range("A4").Value = "'" & CStr(d)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String` function:

```vb
Value = CDec(1) / CDec(11) 
? Format(Value, "0." & String(28, "0"))
0.0909090909090909090909090909
```

Comment: If `value`  is of type `variant`  `?Value` resp. `debug.print value`  will give in this case the same result

Comment: @Storax: Yes, `Value` should be declared to match the data type of the variables. For _Decimal_, VBA only offers _Variant_.

Comment: Yes, sure, but my point is that in case of `Cdec(1)/CDec(10)` the result `0,1000000000000000000000000000`  does not make much sense in terms of _display all digits to the right_  That's is IMHO also true for `Format(Value, "0." & String(40, "0"))` in case of `CDec(1) / CDec(11)`.

Comment: @Storax: I see your point now. Yes. `CStr` fits the bill.